# Simple PHP maths function

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need some help with a small php problem. But i dont know how to approach it.

There is a function called

```
<td><?=$currentCourse['price']?></td>
```

What i need this function to do is to take 20% off whatever the $currentCourse['price'].

Comment: This is not a function, but an array!

Comment: Is the answer for `round()` function okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating a function, you need to use `()` and not `[]`. The `[]` is used to get the array index for arrays!

For your function, you can do this:

```
<?php
    function currentCourse($price)
    {
        return ($price * 0.8);
    }
?>
```

Or if you wanna use the same thing without a function, you can do this way:

```
<td><?=($currentCourse['price'] * 0.8)?></td>
```

But instead of using short tags, I would suggest you to use this:

```
<td><?php echo ($currentCourse['price'] * 0.8); ?></td>
```

Coz, by default, `short_tags` are `Off`.

### Round Function

```
<?php
    echo round(3.4);         // 3
    echo round(3.5);         // 4
    echo round(3.6);         // 4
    echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
    echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
    echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
    echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
    echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
?>
```

Comment: I like this method! its very simple but is there anyway to round the number of by to the nearest decimal point? Example: result 123.3 not 30.

Comment: Yea, you can use `round()` function to round off to the nearest integer. I have updated the answer with the examples of `round()` function.

Answer (score 3):

```
<td><?=$currentCourse['price']*0.8?></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this method!! its very simple but is there anyway to round the number of by to the nearest decimal point? Example: result 123.3 not 30.

Comment: @SophieRhodes Use of Short Operand Tags should be avoided. Anyways, all the best!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function getPercentOff($price, $percent = 20)
{
    return $price * (1 - ($percent/100));
}
?>
```

That would be a relatively generic solution for what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly the short tag operand `<?=` is depreciated, dont use that

```
<td><?php echo getPrice($currentCourse['price']);?></td>    

function getPrice($price){
return $price * 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Deprected? To tell you the fact, from PHP 5.4.0 they are always available.